# Installed Linux Mint on a dual-boot system. Cannot boot Windows 7 anymore

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot, grub

My system initially had Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 installed on two separate hard-disks. The system uses UEFI. The Grub boot menu used to show up and show me boot options for Windows and Ubuntu.

Yesterday, I installed Linux Mint 17 on the same drive that had Ubuntu 14.04. Now I've noticed that Windows 7 doesn't show up in the grub boot menu. Furthermore, I can't use the BIOS boot menu to boot off the drive containing Windows 7; it simply doesn't boot off it at all, and eventually just ends up booting Linux Mint (not sure if this is simply due to the BIOS deciding that booting of that disk has failed, so it's trying the next available disk).

I ran `update-grub` and `os-prober`. The latter says that no volumes were found and says nothing about Windows 7. I even booted up an image of [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) which didn't do anything either. It shows Linux Mint and a memtest image, but still no windows.

I ran the [bootinfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) script and [this](http://pastebin.com/CCRyyJJh) is the output.

The summary is as follows:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Linux Mint 17 Qiana
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows XP: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:
```

`sdc` is an external hard-drive. `sda` contains Linux Mint and `sdb` contains Windows.

Comment: Are you sure that mint 17 support UEFI boot mode?

Comment: Kasra, I believe so. I know Ubuntu 14.04 does and Mint 17 is built off that.

Comment: If i remember i saw that mint 17 support `uefi` and as i know for ubuntu only the 64 bit version support it ! be sure that the version of mint 17 you are using support it !

Comment: I think I might have messed up the install because I installed using regular mode and not UEFI mode (i.e, that's what I chose when the boot options came up in the BIOS). It's fine though because I can mount the drive fine to backup files. I've reinstalled Mint 17 in UEFI mode and I'm going to either try to repair windows or just install over it.

Comment: So Windows is showing up in sdb? If I'm correct (though I really may not be - I am not that knowledgeable yet in Linux) sdb is used for any externally mounted device.